# python maya, function call 2 functions, force to run both

Tags: python, polygon, mesh, maya

I made a windowUI with a button to run 2 functions so I defined a new function to run the other 2

```
def addSlider_splitLoop():
    addSlider()
    splitLoop()

mc.button(label ='Combo' , command = 'addSlider_splitLoop()' )
```

when the button is pressed, only 1 function works:

- when nothing is selected the command only runs the addSlider() function,
- when the polygon loop is selected the command only runs the splitLoop() function

which actually make sense, but does not help me, and changing the order ot the functions also does not help

I want to force it to run both functions, how can I do this?

actually the best thing would be to have the addSlider() to run only when the splitLoop() works, but I'm a real beginner and I have no clue how to do this... force to run both functions might be a dirty solution but is enough for me at the moment

this is the full code anyway (the combo button is just for testing)

```
import maya.cmds as mc

def addSlider_splitLoop():
        addSlider()
        splitLoop()    




def addSlider():
        mc.floatSliderGrp( minValue = 1.00 , maxValue = 99.00 , value = 50.00 , field = True )

def splitLoop():    
        mc.ConvertSelectionToContainedEdges()
        mc.polySplitRing(sma = 180 , wt = 0.5)
        mc.polyDuplicateEdge(ch = True , of = loopDistance() )
        #addSlider()




def doubleLoop():
        mc.ConvertSelectionToContainedEdges()
        mc.polySplitRing(sma = 180 , wt = 0.5)
        mc.polyDuplicateEdge(ch = True , of = loopDistance() )
        mc.polyDelEdge(e = False, cv = True,)
        #addSlider()

def loopDistance():
        distance =  mc.floatSliderGrp('LoopDistanceValue' , query = True, value = True)
        convertedDistance = distance / 100
        return convertedDistance    



def splitLoopUI():

        if mc.window('splitLoopUI' , exists = True):
            mc.deleteUI('splitLoopUI')

        mc.window('splitLoopUI')

        mc.frameLayout( label='                            set loop distance')
        mc.floatSliderGrp('LoopDistanceValue' , minValue = 1.00 , maxValue = 99.00 , value = 50.00 , field = True )    

        mc.button(label ='Triple Loop' , command = 'splitLoop()' ) 
        mc.button(label ='Double Loop' , command = 'doubleLoop()' )
        mc.button(label ='Combo' , command = 'addSlider_splitLoop()' )

        mc.text( label=' +   edit loop distance   + ')

        mc.scrollLayout( 'scrollLayout' )
        mc.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )


        mc.showWindow('splitLoopUI')
splitLoopUI()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things going on here.

1. Don't call the scripts as strings -- that's a recipe for wierdness down the road. Pass the function objects instead, as in @Dr.Weeny's example.  It's more reliable and actually faster as well.  [More here](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/04/maya-callbacks-cheat-sheet.html)
2. In your posted code `addSlider()` doesn't do any work to get the currently active GUI object -- depending on when it runs that slider could be showing up anywhere -- in the channel box, in some other window, or it could be failing.  This is probably why it seems like the function isn't running: you're just not spotting the new slider wherever it ends up. Try adding a debug print.
3. if you want to run `addSlider()` after other commands, the simplest thing to do is probably to have all of the tool commands return a value indicating that they have succeeded or failed:

   ```
   def splitLoop():    
       try:
           mc.ConvertSelectionToContainedEdges()
           mc.polySplitRing(sma = 180 , wt = 0.5)
           return mc.polyDuplicateEdge(ch = True , of = loopDistance() )
        except:
            return None

   def addSlider_splitLoop():
       if splitLoop():
           addSlider()
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I know that my addSlider() does not effect anythying yet, I wanted to link it to the channelbox later (not sure yet how to get the last one), but first I wanted to check if I can add a new slider to the UI for every time I run the command

You are right, the slider is created every time, just not in my window, only the first time I press the button the slider appears in the correct window, every other time is somewhere else I cant see... how can I make it create the slider in the correct window?

Comment: You need to store the name of the layout where you want it to go and use `mc.setParent()` to make it active before you add the new slider

Answer (score 0):

You should not putting comma on your function command.
You could try to use mc.evalDeferred('addSlider()\nsplitLoop()').
You may use try: except: finally:

As I can't test your script, it is hard to figure what should do both of your functions. In my opinion, it is a problem of idle time and you should scratch your head over evalDeferred command.

```
   def addSlider_splitLoop():
        addSlider()
        splitLoop()

    mc.button(label ='Combo' , command = addSlider_splitLoop)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm taking a look at this evalDeferred, but I'm not sure I need it in my case. (by the way I edited the question and added the full code for testing)